# Alternative to github-cli after Precise

Tags: 13.04, 13.10, github

```
$ ghi
The program 'ghi' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install github-cli
$ sudo apt-get install github-cli
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package github-cli
$ uname -a
Linux machine-t440s 3.8.0-35-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 3 01:24:59 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

[packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=github-cli) says it's available only on `Precise` but I'd just like the similar feature of this (particularly like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5046150/577001)). Is there any alternative available for newer Ubuntu distros?

(By the way I know I should not be on `Raring` now that no one takes care of it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab the Precise package from the [Launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/github-cli), and should be able to install it again on a newer version of Ubuntu. The package was simply synchronized over from Debian. I'm not sure why it's not synchronized over for newer versions of Ubuntu, as it does seem to still exist in Debian (whre you could also grab the package from instead, if you would prefer).